# Variable length differ in regression loop with NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, variables, linear-regression

asking for your help once again. I am trying to run a loop on the creation of different linear regressions on a given dataframe (over 400 columns). A few lines have some NA values which I try to omit by using na.action=na.omit but when I run the loop R gives me the following message.

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = funds[, i] ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB +  : 
>       variable lengths differ (found for 'factors$Mkt.RF')

Can someone help me out here? See below the lines of code and an excerpt of my data. If you need any additional data, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

```
funds <- as.data.frame(funds, row.names = NULL)
factors <- as.data.frame(factors, row.names =  NULL)

set.seed(1)
out <- data.frame(NULL)              
for (i in 1:length(funds)) {
     m <- summary(lm(funds[,i] ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB + factors$HML + factors$MOM, na.action = na.exclude), data = funds)
     out[i, 1] <- names(y)[i]           
     out[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   
     out[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   
     out[i, 4] <- m$coefficients[3,1]   
     out[i, 5] <- m$coefficients[4,1]   
}

names(out) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x")
```

Output:

```
    > rownames(funds) <- funds$Date
    > funds$Date <- NULL

    > 
    > rownames(factors) <- factors$Date
    > factors$Date <- NULL

    > set.seed(1)
    > out <- data.frame(NULL)              
    > for (i in 1:length(funds)) {
    +      m <- summary(lm(funds[,i] ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB + factors$HML + factors$MOM, na.action = na.exclude), data = funds)
    +      out[i, 1] <- names(y)[i]           
    +      out[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   
    +      out[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   
    +      out[i, 4] <- m$coefficients[3,1]   
    +      out[i, 5] <- m$coefficients[4,1]   
    + }
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = funds[, i] ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB +  : 
      variable lengths differ (found for 'factors$Mkt.RF')
```

DPUT:

```
#Factor variable
structure(list(Mkt.RF = c(-0.06, 4.18, 0.13, 0.46, 5.44), SMB = c(-0.56, 
-0.1, -1.6, 0.43, 1.41), HML = c(4.83, 3.17, -2.67, 0.6, 4.93
), RF = c(0.25, 0.26, 0.3, 0.25, 0.3), MOM = c(0.44, -2.01, 3.59, 
4.19, 3.01)), row.names = 192701:192705, class = "data.frame")

#Below my "Funds" variable
structure(list(LPA0HHC9 = c(7.8230315, -2.3377663, -1.5936528, 
1.6568067, 2.1277897, -2.457893, 1.5437286, -5.560534, 0.357859, 
0.212156, -2.4966745, -9.730683, 5.7866847, -6.2293317, 5.0703387, 
-1.5625391), LPA0HNP2 = c(4.6186144, 0.8695652, 0.530504, 1.9788918, 
1.9404916, -1.4593909, 3.86349, -1.6738996, 2.5851198, 3.0731407, 
0.0596303, -2.920143, 5.2179251, -1.6919487, -0.1780415, 1.1890606
), LPA0HNP3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.9, 
-2.8741328, 4.3877551, -1.4662757, 0.0992063, 1.1892963), LPA0HNP4 = c(5.1759834, 
0.656168, 0, 2.2164276, 2.2959184, -0.4987531, 2.443609, -1.2844037, 
2.2924411, 3.4524531, 0.8782201, -2.9599536, 4.3062201, -1.4908257, 
-0.0582072, 1.1648224), LPA0J22F = c(4.753623, -0.5246329, 0.3443459, 
3.0796593, 2.1799129, 0.0715029, 4.054363, -2.0230006, 2.0954634, 
3.3837521, 0.9665872, -3.9676485, 5.5744768, -0.568624, 1.6424237, 
1.1643458)), row.names = c("28.02.2014", "31.03.2014", "30.04.2014", 
"31.05.2014", "30.06.2014", "31.07.2014", "31.08.2014", "30.09.2014", 
"31.10.2014", "30.11.2014", "31.12.2014", "31.01.2015", "28.02.2015", 
"31.03.2015", "30.04.2015", "31.05.2015"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share the data using `dput` here?

Comment: Hello Mr. Shah, I added the dput. I had to truncate a few values since it was too long. Sorry if it is too long, but I am a R newbie. Thank you for your help

Comment: only sharing `head` of data `dput` is enough. Something which we can copy/paste into our session. We cannot copy incomplete `dput` into our R session. Can you also explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Dear Mr. Shah, thank you, finally understood how dput works. Thanks. What I want to do is to create a loop that regresses the "factor" variable on each column in "funds" - which are approximately 400 columns. Then I would like to save all the results in a new variable to be able to export it.  However, because of the error listed above, I am unable to carry that out. Your help would be great, thank you!!

Comment: But how would you regress against different dataframes? As shown in the error message they have different lengths. Running for one example, see it works for data in same dataframe `lm(LPA0HHC9 ~ LPA0HNP2 + LPA0HNP3, na.action = na.exclude, data = funds)` but doesn't work for data in different dataframes `lm(LPA0HHC9 ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB + factors$HML + factors$MOM, na.action = na.exclude, data = funds)`